# DataTables Plugin - Align buttons to the right

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using this plugin: https://www.datatables.net/

I have a table listing all the news of the website, with: date, title, status and some actions (add, edit, delete), see here: [image: add news]

And I want to put all those buttons aligned to the right.
Exactly like that:
[image: yeah baby]

(I just have this result because i edited on photoshop)

How can I do that? I tried with some "align right" but it doesn't work like i want...

Can someone help me? :)

My code:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "<b>_TOTAL_</b> resultados encontrados"
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to set `autoWidth` to false, and define `columns` so the "button column" has a fixed width and the other columns a relative percent width close to 100%. It is important to avoid wordwrapping in the button column too. Example

```css
td.buttons {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    columns : [
        { width: '50%' },
        { width: '40%' },
        { width: '100px', class : 'buttons' }
   ]     
})
```

small demo (OP has not provided an example) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pebmuu4w/**

---

NB: I assume you are using 1.10.x since you are just referring to dataTables in general. If not the above options is named `bAutoWidth`, `aoColumns`, `sWidth` and `sClass`.

Comment: Using the Dom options ("dom": 'rfBltip',) worked for me:  http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html